# Not Able to post asynchronously in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, post, async-await

I am basically new to react and just following a guided project from a YouTube channel.
I am half way in this project.
From app js Form component is called and in Form component when i click on submit it calls `createPost()` function in "client/src/actions/posts.js" and the data gets dispatched even though async and await keyword present in `createPost()` it is not posting asynchronisingly. It shows error in try block which is in `createPost()`

> Cannot destructure property 'data' of '(intermediate value)' as it is
> undefined

but inside that createPost() another createPost() is called which is in "client/src/api/index.js" where axios is used to post the data. When i try to console log the response over there in browser console i am getting

> status:201
> statusText:"Created"

After this when i reloaded the data are posted and it is reflecting in the UI. I believe this is because of async and await keyword not working. In vscode the await keyword present in `createPosst()` which is in "client/src/actions/posts.js" gets underlined and shows `'await' has no effect on the type of this expression.` (Please refer createPost() function in "client/src/actions/posts.js").I have attached the code files below . Thank you.

## Client Folder Structure

```
    ▼ client  
      > node_modules  
      > public  
      ▼ src  
        ▼ actions
            posts.js
        ▼ api
            index.js
        ▼ components
            ▼ Form
              Form.js
              styles.js
            ▼ Posts
              ▼ Post
                Post.js
                styles.js
              Posts.js
              styles.js     
        ▼ images
            15.png
        ▼ reducers
            index.js
            posts.js
        App.js
        index.js
        styles.js
     .gitignore
      package.json
      yarn.lock
```

### client/src/Index.js

```
    import React from "react";
    import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
    import { Provider } from "react-redux";
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
    import thunk from "redux-thunk";
    import {reducers} from "./reducers/index";
    import App from "./App.js";
    
    const store = createStore(reducers, compose(applyMiddleware(thunk)));
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
      </Provider>,
        document.getElementById('root')
      );
```

### client/src/App.js

```
    import React, {useEffect} from "react";
    import {
      Container,
      AppBar,
      Typography,
      // Groe,
      Grid,
      Grow,
    } from "@material-ui/core";
    import {useDispatch} from 'react-redux';
    import {getPosts} from './actions/posts';
    import Posts from "./components/Posts/Posts.js";
    import Form from "./components/Form/Form.js";
    import useStyles from './styles';
    import img from "./images/15.png";
    
    export default function App() {
      const classes = useStyles();
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      useEffect(()=>{
        dispatch(getPosts());
      },[dispatch])
      return (
        <Container maxwidth="lg">
          <AppBar className={classes.appBar} position="static" color="inherit">
            <Typography className={classes.heading} varient="h2" align="center">
              Memories
            </Typography>
            <img className={classes.image} src={img} alt="memories" height="60" />
          </AppBar>
          <Grow in>
            <Container>
              <Grid
                container
                justifyContent="space-between"
                alignItems="stretch"
                spacing={3}
              >
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={7}>
                  <Posts />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={4}>
                  <Form />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </Container>
          </Grow>
        </Container>
      );
    }
```

### client/src/actions/posts.js

```
    import * as api from '../api';
    export const getPosts = () => async(dispatch)=>{
        try{
            const {data} = await api.fetchPosts();
            dispatch({type:'FETCH_ALL',payload:data});
        }catch (error){
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    }
    
    export const createPost = (post) => async(dispatch) =>{
        try{
            //In vscode when i hoover over the below await keyword it shows like below
            //'await' has no effect on the type of this expression. 
            const {data}  =  await api.createPost(post)
            dispatch({type:'CREATE',payload:data})
            
        }catch (error){
            console.log(error.message)
        }
    }
```

### client/src/api/index.js

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    
    const url = 'http://localhost:5000/posts';
    
    export const fetchPosts = () => axios.get(url);
    export const createPost = (newPost) => {
        axios.post(url,newPost).then((res)=>console.log(res))};
```

### client/src/components/Form/Form.js

```
    import React, { useState} from "react";
    import { TextField, Button, Typography, Paper } from "@material-ui/core";
    import useStyles from "./styles";
    import FileBase from "react-file-base64";
    import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
    import { createPost } from "../../actions/posts";
    
    export default function Form() {
      const classes = useStyles();
      const dispatch = useDispatch();
      const [postData, setPostData] = useState({
        creator: "",
        title: "",
        message: "",
        tags: "",
        selectedfile: "",
      });
      const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(createPost(postData));
      };
      const clear = () => {};
      return (
        <Paper className={classes.paper}>
          <form
            autoComplete="off"
            noValidate
            className={`${classes.root} ${classes.form}`}
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          >
            <Typography variant="h6">creating a Memory</Typography>
            <TextField
              name="creator"
              variant="outlined"
              label="Creator"
              fullWidth
              value={postData.creator}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setPostData({ ...postData, creator: e.target.value })
              }
            />
            <TextField
              name="title"
              variant="outlined"
              label="Title"
              fullWidth
              value={postData.title}
              onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, title: e.target.value })}
            />
            <TextField
              name="message"
              variant="outlined"
              label="Message"
              fullWidth
              value={postData.message}
              onChange={(e) =>
                setPostData({ ...postData, message: e.target.value })
              }
            />
            <TextField
              name="tags"
              variant="outlined"
              label="Tags"
              fullWidth
              value={postData.tags}
              onChange={(e) => setPostData({ ...postData, tags: e.target.value })}
            />
            <div className={classes.fileInput}>
              <FileBase
                type="file"
                multiple={false}
                onDone={({ base64 }) =>
                  setPostData({ ...postData, selectedFile: base64 })
                }
              />
            </div>
            <Button
              className={classes.buttonSubmit}
              variant="contained"
              color="primary"
              size="large"
              type="submit"
              fullWidth
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              color="secondary"
              size="small"
              onClick={clear}
              fullWidth
            >
              clear
            </Button>
          </form>
        </Paper>
      );
    }
```

### client/src/reducers/posts.js

```
    export default (posts=[],action) =>{
        switch (action.type){
            case 'FETCH_ALL':
                return action.payload;
            case 'CREATE':{
                return [...posts,action.payload];}
            default:
                return posts;
        }
    }
```

### client/src/reducers/index.js

```
    import { combineReducers } from "redux";
    import posts from "./posts";
    
    export const reducers= combineReducers({
      posts:posts,
    });
```

## Server Folder Structure

```
    ▼ server
      ▼ controllers
          posts.js
      ▼ models
          postMessage.js
      > node_modukes
      ▼ routes
          posts.js
      index.js
      package.json
      yarn.lock
```

### server/controllers/posts.js

```
    import PostMessage from "../models/postMessage.js";
        
        export const getPosts = async (req, res) => {
          try {
            const postMessages = await PostMessage.find();
            res.status(200).json(postMessages);
          } catch (error) {
            res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
          }
        };
        
        export const createPost = async (req, res) => {
          const post = req.body;
          const newPost = new PostMessage(post);
          try {
            await newPost.save();
            res.status(201).json(newPost);
          } catch {
            res.status(409).json({ message: error.message });
          }
        };
```

### server/models/postMessage.js

```
    import mongoose from 'mongoose';
    
    const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
        title: String,
        message: String,
        creator: String,
        tags: [String],
        selectedFile: String,
        likeCount: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0,
        },
        createdAt: {
            type: Date,
            default: new Date(),
        },
    })
    
    var PostMessage = mongoose.model('PostMessage', postSchema);
    
    export default PostMessage;
```

### server/routes/posts.js

```
    import express from "express";
    import { getPosts, createPost } from "../controllers/posts.js";
    const router = express.Router();
    
    router.get("/", getPosts);
    router.post("/", createPost);
    
    export default router;
```

### server/index.js

```
    import express from "express";
    import bodyParser from "body-parser";
    import mongoose from "mongoose";
    import cors from "cors";
    import postRoutes from "./routes/posts.js";
    
    const app = express();
    app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "30mb", extended: true }));
    app.use(cors());
    app.use("/posts", postRoutes);
    
    const CONNECTION_URL ="...(connection url provided correctly in code)";
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
    
    mongoose
      .connect(CONNECTION_URL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
      .then(() => app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Port:${PORT}`)))
      .catch((error) => console.log(error.message));
```

Comment: Because your data get the empty value you didn't return the response. you need to return  the API response from client/src/api/index.js here

Comment: When i try to return the api it shows cannot read the property of undefined in console Can you please explain with code

Comment: You can check out my repo. I have implemented it here https://github.com/nazmulweb/simple-mern-blog

Comment: I have checked your repo but for me `client/src/api/index.js` it seems to be same as mine can you please explain with code.

Comment: It should work if it is the same as mine. can you share your repo please where I can check your whole code?

Comment: Thank you sir Now its working after codeing like below
`export const createPost = (newPost) =>axios.post(url,newPost).then((res)=>res); `

Comment: But the below code is same as the following code know only there is a console message extra.
Code which you suggested
`export const createPost = (newPost) => axios.post(url, newPost);`
Code which i gave
` export const createPost = (newPost) =>`  { `axios.post(url,newPost).then((res)=>console.log(res))};`

Comment: If you use the arrow function with { } brackets, you need to use the return keyword. on the other hand, if you use without { } brackets, you don't need to use the return keyword. it will return the value by default. to know more about the arrow function you can see it https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `client/src/api/index.js` you didn't return the API response. You need to return the response like this

```
export const createPost = (newPost) => {
  return axios.post(url, newPost).then((res)=> res )
};
```

or

```
export const createPost = (newPost) => axios.post(url, newPost);
```